# How to close context menu when switching to another frame?

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-listfragment

I have an app with two fragments, every fragment has a listview. When selecting elements from the list the context menu appears automatically, I handle events an so on ... so far so good, but my problem is when I change to the other fragment, the context menu keeps visible so user may get confused thinking that it is the context menu from the current visible list view.

I've tried calling

```
getActivity().closeContextMenu();
```

when switching between fragments but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: if two fragment in same activity then just in second fragment onCreate check whether the context Menu is open then close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

I am using ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL for multiple selection, at the MultiChoiceModeListener I save the actionmode for later use:

```
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
   // item selected
   Log.d("FilesFragment.ContextMenu", "onItemCheckedStateChanged(); position: " + position);
   actionmode = mode; // <- I save the action mode for later use
   listadapter.getItem(position).setSelected(checked);
}
```

Then when I detect that user wants to change to another tab-frame I call

```
if (actionmode!=null){
  actionmode.finish();
}
```